# URL not found when trying to make a request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, request, postman

I tried to make a post request in Postman to the server(WebApi) to save an item.

This is the error message

> {
>       "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:63924/api/user/save'.",
>       "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'user'."
>   }

This is the request url:

> http://localhost:63924/api/user/save

The body:

> {
>           "Email": "sue@me.com",
>           "Password": "1234",
>           "FirstName": "Sue",
>           "LastName": "Smith",
>           "Id": 4,
>           "IsDeleted": false
>       },

The controller :

```
 public class UserController : Controller
{
    private IService<UserDTO> service;

    public UserController(IService<UserDTO> _service)
    {
        this.service = _service;
    }
    // GET: User
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/user/save")]                      //HERE IS THE ROUTE
    public void AddUser(UserDTO userDTO)
    {
        service.Add(userDTO);
    }
}
```

Why the URL can't be found?

Comment: Can you try to add `public void AddUser([FromBody]UserDTO userDTO)` and try postman

Comment: Just curious, is your `GET` method working?

Answer (score 2):

Change you route to simply "save", because of Web API default route is ..api/{contollername}

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("save")]
    public void AddUser(UserDTO userDTO)
    {
      service.Add(userDTO);
    }
```